# Positioning <span> image in a photogallery

Tags: css

I am using HTML and CSS to create a 'hover over' photo gallery, the 'hover over' producing a large image below the thumbnail'
My HTML looks like the following:

```
<div id="container">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img src="thumb1.jpg" /><span><img src="photo1.jpg" /><br />Simply beautiful.</span></a>
```

I have set the container to be 900px wide and repeated the line below it 8 times.
This positions the 8 thumbnails in a line starting in the top left hand corner of the container.

I can set the position of the image to come below this line of thumbs using "top" in the CSS code, but cannot set the left-right position of the image.
It always starts to the right of the appropriate thumbnail.

I seem to have tried everything, but hope I haven't.

Help! Please.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS should help:

```
.thumbnail {
    position: relative;
}

.thumbnail span {
    display: none;
}

.thumbnail:hover span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;

    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

This should position the span to same distance from the left edge as the thumb.

A working example:

> http://www.ulmanen.fi/stuff/hoverthumb/

Comment: This does exactly what mine does.
I want the larger picture to come in the same place irrespective of which thumb is hovered over

Iain

Comment: To the same position in the page irregardless of where the thumb is? Then drop the `position: relative` from the `.thumbnail` and position the span absolutely. That way the span isn't relative to the thumbnail.